# import shared library in a stage in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

i am trying to call a sharedlibrary class and its method into a jenkins pipeline in a particular stage... is there a way to call it without declaring the library at the top with LIBRARY IDENTIFIER I am importing multiple library
I am loading those library with library identifier out of 2 I have to call a method out of one library

```
library identifier: "lib-1@", retriever: legacySCM([ $class: 'SCM', branches: [[name: '' ]], userRemoteConfigs: [[ credentialsId: <cred>, url: <url> ]] ])

library identifier: "lib-2@", retriever: legacySCM([ $class: 'SCM', branches: [[name: '']], userRemoteConfigs: [[ credentialsId: <cred>, url: <url2> ]] ])


   `  stage('stage') {
 
    }`
```

now i have to call a method of .groovy file from lib-1 in any stage. how can i do that. i am loading multiple libraries at the top in every run.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: elaborated the question above.